Function returned without value in Oracle
I made my first function in Oracle database, but its returned with error (ORA-06503):

ORA-06503: PL/SQL: Function returned without value

function GetNumberOfReceipt(psID varchar2) return number is

nID_Order number;
nID_Bill number;
nID_DeliveryNO number;
nID_WithoutDeliveryNO number;
nID number;
nExists number;

begin

select count(*) into nExists from <mytable> where <mywhereclause> = psID;

--query blocks

--ORDER
select id into nID_Order from <mytables> where <mywhereclause> = psID group by id;
--PL
select id into nID_Bill from <mytables>  where <mywhereclause> = psID group by id;
--DeliveryNote
select id into nID_DeliveryNO from <mytables> where <mywhereclause>=psID;
--DeriveryNoteWithout
select id into nID_WithoutDeliveryNO from <mytables> where <mywhereclause> =psID;


--Format multiple values/IDs
select listagg(ID,',') within group(order by ID ) into nID from (
select nID_Order as ID from dual
union all
select nID_Bill as ID from dual
union all
select nID_DeliveryNO as ID from dual
union all
select nID_WithoutDeliveryNO as ID from dual
group by nID_Order,nID_Bill,nID_DeliveryNO,nID_WithoutDeliveryNO);


IF nExists=0 THEN
--raise
<myerrormsg> -- pckg procedure
ELSE
return nID;
END IF;

exception
when no_data_found then
nID := 0;

end GetNumberOfReceipt;

In the query block, the queries are working, because i tested each one.
Should i delete the if condition ? Or what did i miss ?

You always need to either raise an exception or return something. In the exception block, no return statement is executed. That could throw this error.

In addition to Koen's comment, your IF statement is pointless where it is - presumably you're doing a check at the top to work out if you need to run the subsequent queries or not. Currently you're running them even there are no rows matching that psid in your table, and in that case, it's jumping to the exception handler on the first query that returns no rows - i.e. you're never getting to the IF statement in that scenario! It's difficult to advise you more as you've oversimplified your queries - hopefully they're not all selecting from the same tables with the same joins each time!

@Boneist, no, they are not same joints, and the tables are not the same. My logic was first check the order id(psID), if not exists or not valid then raise. If receipt id (ID in select) not exists then return it to 0. (nID:=0) Because, can be order which was not dispatched..and it has no ID(select id), but has order number.

So if the order id doesn't exist, you want to raise that as an error? I.e. stop any processing and output an exception to the calling code?

As Koen pointed out in the comments, the issue is that you have an exception block that doesn't raise an exception or return a value.
However, the flow of your function doesn't really make sense - why are you checking for the existence of an order id, but not doing anything about it until the end?
Also, why collect all the ids into their various variables only to write a dummy query to concatenate them all; why not do all that in a single query?
I think your function would be more efficient if you rewrote it to be something like:
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION getnumberofreceipt(psid VARCHAR2) RETURN NUMBER IS

  nid                   NUMBER;
  nexists               NUMBER;

BEGIN

  SELECT COUNT(*)
  INTO   nexists
  FROM   < mytable >
  WHERE  < mywhereclause > = psid;

  IF nexists = 0 -- Moved the IF statement here, to avoid doing unnecessary work when we know the order id doesn't exist
  THEN
    -- either raise an exception here via RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(), or set the nid variable to a dummy value, depending on your requirements

  ELSE

    -- combined all your queries into one. Depending on the tables and join conditions in each subquery, it may be possible to combine the queries further,
    -- but it's difficult to say because you've over-simplified your queries.
    WITH         orders AS (SELECT ID -- if you're only selecting this one column, you can remove the group by and just use DISTINCT instead
                            FROM   < mytables >
                            WHERE  < mywhereclause > = psid
                            GROUP  BY ID),
                     pl AS (SELECT id -- if you're only selecting this one column, you can remove the group by and just use DISTINCT instead
                            FROM   < mytables >
                            WHERE  < mywhereclause > = psid
                            GROUP  BY ID),
           deliverynote AS (SELECT ID
                            FROM   < mytables >
                            WHERE  < mywhereclause >= psid),
    DeriveryNoteWithout AS (SELECT id
                            INTO   nid_withoutdeliveryno
                            FROM   < mytables >
                            WHERE  < mywhereclause > = psid)
    --Format multiple values/IDs
    SELECT listagg(id, ',') within GROUP(ORDER BY id)
    INTO   nid
    FROM   (SELECT id
            FROM   orders
            UNION -- Using UNIONs instead of UNION ALLs because it seems we only want unique IDs
            SELECT id
            FROM   pl
            UNION
            SELECT id
            FROM   deliverynote
            UNION
            SELECT id
            FROM   deriverynotewithout);

  END IF;

  RETURN nid; -- Arguably, it's good practice to have a single point of return in the main block
              -- i.e. set the variable at the relevant points and then return it at the end.

END getnumberofreceipt;
/

N.B. this will handle the case where you could get multiple ids returned for a given psid, whereas your original function would raise a TOO_MANY_ROWS error. If that's desired behaviour, you're stuck with your current separate queries.
